# Contingency table of pandas Series with null values

Tags: pandas

Suppose you have:

```
import pandas as pd

x = pd.Series(["A", "B", "A", "A", None, "B", "A", None], dtype = "category")
y = pd.Series([ 1,   2,   3,  None, 1,    2,   3,   2])
```

If you do `pd.crosstab(x, y, dropna = False)`, you get:

```
col_0  1.0  2.0  3.0
row_0               
A        1    0    2
B        0    2    0
```

which omits the three (`x`, `y`) pairs for which one of the values is null. (The parameter `dropna` is [misleadingly named](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/10772).) How can I create a contingency table that includes these values, like the table below?

```
col_0  1.0  2.0  3.0  NaN
row_0               
A        1    0    2    1
B        0    2    0    0
NaN      1    1    0    0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would converting the `NaN` to a string work?

```
pd.crosstab(x.replace(np.nan, 'NaN'),y.replace(np.nan, 'NaN'),dropna=False)
```

Result:

```
col_0  1.0  2.0  3.0  NaN
row_0                    
A        1    0    2    1
B        0    2    0    0
NaN      1    1    0    0
```

Comment: I tried something like this with `Series.map` and it didn't work for the categorical Series. I wasn't even aware `Series.replace` existed.